# How to set an HTML Element to a Javascript function and make sure it happens after the HTML is available?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have declared a Javascript function which basically goes through a for-loop and prints to the console in every loop. I am trying to set my HTML-element to that function:

`function otherFunction(){ document.getElementById('element').innerHMTL = function();}`

I know that the Javascript is executed before the HTML loads fully but even if I try to
use `window.addEvenListener("load", otherFunction())` it still says

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null

which I guess means my HTML-element (simple empty div with an id) does not even exist yet, so I would like to know how I should use the EventListener properly.

Comment: What do you mean by "set an element to a function"? - that's meaningless. I think you mean "show the output of my function inside my element".

Comment: `otherFunction()`  executes the function. You'll want `window.addEvenListener("load", otherFunction)`

Comment: Tip: spot the difference between `window.addEvenListener("load", otherFunction())` and `window.addEvenListener("load", otherFunction )`. (Also, consider using `'DOMContentLoaded'` instead of `'load'`).

Comment: @Dai yes indeed, that was poorly phrased, sorry! Thanks for the suggestion @Dai and @Kooilnc I do not receive the error anymore after removing the parentheses and `'DOMContentLoaded'` worked great as well!